# Spin groups and Clifford Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

Consider $\Bbb R^n$ with standard norm and its Clifford algebra $Cl(\Bbb R^n)$. It decomposes as  $Cl(\Bbb R^n)=Cl_0(\Bbb R^n)\oplus Cl_1(\Bbb R^n)$ (even part and odd part).  The group $\text{Spin}(n) \subset Cl_0(\Bbb R^n)$ is defined to be $\{v_1 \cdots v_r : v_i\in \Bbb R^n, |v_i|=1, r \textrm{ even}\}$ (the multiplication $v_1\cdots v_r$ is taken in $Cl(\Bbb R^n)$). (I am following Lawson, Michelson's book *Spin Geometry*.) It is known that $Cl_0(\Bbb R^n)$ is isomorphic to $Cl(\Bbb R^{n-1})$, so we can regard $\text{Spin}(n)\subset Cl(\Bbb R^{n-1})$.  Theorem 8.1 (p.50) of the book asserts that $\text{Spin}(3)\cong SU(2)$, $\text{Spin}(4)\cong SU(2)\times SU(2)$, etc. In the proof, it is written that any representation of $Cl(\Bbb R^{n-1})$ on $\Bbb C^m$ or $\Bbb H^m$ can be assumed to have the property that, when restricted to the group $\text{Spin}(n)$, it preserves the standard hermitian inner product. But I can't see why. Why is this assumption possible?

Comment: If $G$ is any compact Lie group with a representation on $V$, and $H(-, -): V \times V \to \mathbb{C}$ is any Hermitian inner product, then the Haar measure on $G$ can be used to define a new Hermitian form $F(v, w) = \int_G H(gv, gw) d\mu(g)$ which is easily checked to be a $G$-invariant inner product. (You might have seen this in the finite group case, where the integral is really a sum over the group elements). If you now pick a basis of $V$ which is orthonormal with respect to $F$, you get an identification of inner product spaces $(V, F) \cong \mathbb{C}^n$.